# How can i add search bar above dropdown menu on Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms

There are around 550+ items on the dropdown list, is it possible to filter them out?

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Why downvote on this question?

Comment: @alexkovelsky [tag:filter] is a meta-tags in this site ref. [Let's clean up some meta tags](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2696/88163), the other tags ([tag:search] and [tag:dropdown]) also looks to be meta-tags.

Comment: @Rubén thanks. Is there a place I can discuss/find out more about this?

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't such an option.

And in any case it would be highly unpractical for anyone to use such a form.

I suggest you split it to more questions. (many more)

Comment: but there are 550+ items? how can i split?

Comment: maybe any add-ons?

Comment: _"but there are 550+ items? how can i split?"_ I suggest you find a way to group them. And no. There are no add-ons for such a thing.

Comment: For example, question "What school did you attend?" And dropdown is to have same name for same school (exclude variants in naming the same school)

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

1. put the long list as a single question on separate section
2. advice users to use Ctrl+F to find the needed option.

This has advantage over drop-down that it's much easier to scroll the whole page than dropdown which user can accidentally close and will need to open and search again.

[image: Google forms search multiple choice]

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to do this on Google Forms, however, there is an alternative.
You can use https://youtu.be/W_PhKrklpBs?t=328

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).